# Will the load average of my Linux box increase if it reaches file descriptors or TCP connections limit?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, tcp, high-load, load-average

Will the load average of my Linux box increase if it reaches file descriptors or TCP connections limit ?

Comment: Not directly, but why don't you try it with your app to make sure?

Comment: File descriptors limits can be increased easily, TCP connections really only by adding extra IP addresses to the server (though there are ways to recycle the available ports quicker than the default). But more information about why you think you would be reaching either limit would be useful.